# Branch.io getShortUrl Universal Branch Object

Tags: ios, swift3, branch.io

The getShortUrl function of the BranchUniversalObject usually works fine.  However, sometimes it will generate a very large url with lots of meta data.

The url normally looks like:

http://exampleapp.com/alias

but every once in a while, for no reason I can tell, I will get back a url containing all the metadata from the link properties.  Something like:

http://exampleapp.com/a/key_live_nin0QyFNUZ2BYh13tBpioevJWClfBoDS?%24identity_id=142989785412097588?alias=alias&channel=app&feature=invite&type=0&duration=0&source=ios&data=eyJ1c2VySWQiOiJnZDIwYnZIFub25pY2VybCI6Imh0dHA6Ly9oZaDVMIiwiJG9nX2ltYWdlX3VybmF3cy5jb20vZmIyODZlZjMxZjU0MjAzOTkzMWZhMDJlMTVjMjRjZTFfZmlsFsX3ZS5iaW4iLCIkY2XljdXJ0c3kuY29tIiwiJG9nX3RpdGxlIjoiR2V0ICQxMCBvZmYgeW91ciBmaXJzdCBkcmVzcyBvbiBDdXJ0cbCI6Imh0dHBzOi8vY3VydHN5LXBhcnNlLWZpbGVzLnMzLmFtYXpv3kiLCIkZXhwX2RhdGUiOjAsIiRwd9pbmRleGFibGUiOjEsInJlZmVWJsaWNseVycmFsIjoicmVmZXJyYWwiLCIkY2Fub25pY2FsX2lkZW50aWZpZXIiOiJnZDIwYnZIaDVMcmVmZXJyYWwifQ==

I have been unable to identify what causes this.

(The url above, I've edited a bit and messed around with it to prevent any identifying info.... I have no ideas where it may go, so don't go to it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally found the answer on their github documentation, but not in the documentation on their website.

"NOTE: If you POST to the this endpoint with the same alias, and a matching set of other POST parameters to an existing aliased link, the original will be returned to you. If it clashes and you don't specify a match, will return a HTTP 409 error."

Debugging, I found that there is a 409 error occurring when I call the function on those will aliased urls on Branch, but not saved to my own backend.  It seems it is also left out that the full url will be returned along with the error.

I basically re-wrote a small part of my code to detect the 409 error, and if it happens, just add a number to the alias

Comment: Alex from Branch.io here: good solution! Sorry we buried the details — we'll try to get that cleared up. Long links can also happen if the link creation call fails, though that is obviously not the issue here.